# How do I get two pistons (one of them on an inverted signal) to go at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Here's the problem - I need two pistons to go at the exact same time, so that one of them is contracted and the other is expanded, on a switch mechanism. To achieve this, one of the pistons has to have an inverted redstone signal, like so.

[image: redstone circuit1]

This would be all fine and dandy except that when the signal is inverted it's slower by the tiniest fraction of a second. So, I add a repeater onto the other piston to slow the signal, but then that one is slower than the other. This problem has stumped me on many of my redstone projects, and any solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: The repeater should make the two occur at the same time. Did you set the repeater down to only 1 tick? It defaults to 4.

Comment: @LyonesGamer a repeater is if you place it on 1 tick... not on 4?

Comment: Does it default to 1? Sorry, I must have had it backwards.

Answer (score 6):

The NOT gate also called inverter delays the time exact one tick.

> circuit delay: 1 tick

<sub>from the [minecraft gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit#NOT_Gate)</sub>

That means the signal on the otherside is one tick to fast. To solve that simply put a repeater in the connection to the other piston.

A repeater also delays the signal with one tick.

> When initially placed, a redstone repeater has a delay of 1 redstone
> tick.

<sub>from the [minecraft gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater#Signal_delay)</sub>

That means your circuit should look like this:

[image: Overview]

I only have the ability to check that with my eyes and ears and it seems pretty at the same time. Anyway you said you tried that...

Here is your secound answer:

There is a thing called instant inverter. It looks like this:

[image: Instant Inverter]

To get the whole thing working remove your inverter and place this instant inverter at this place. Keep in mind that the piston with the inverter acts strange. But this does not influence the block movememt. Neiter from a normal or sticky piston.

[image: With Instand Inverter]

> circuit delay: 0 ticks

<sub>from the [minecraft gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit#NOT_Gate)</sub>

You find other instant inverter possibilitys in the source link above.

Comment: It's not the not gate itself causing the delay, it is the redstone torch taking one tick to toggle state that is causing the delay. So anywhere you have a redstone torch being toggled, add a tick to your delay.